# MongoDB in Go in relation to JSON and BSON

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mongodb-query, mgo

I'm learning how to use the community maintained `mgo` repo linked [here](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo).

I've discovered through this [example](https://gist.github.com/border/3489566) that the way to query for some pieces of data seems to be done through BSON (The community maintained version of the BSON library is linked [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson)):

```
type Person struct {
    Name      string
    Phone     string
}

c.Find(bson.M{"name": "Alice"}).All(&result)
```

Which will give me all `Person` with name `Alice`.

I have also discovered that I don't need BSON to do this query. `Find()` takes any interface:

```
c.Find(Person{
    Name: "Alice",
    Phone: "1234",
}).All(&result)
```

Will also work, but only returning the specified exact query. If I leave out piece of the struct like this:

```
c.Find(Person{
    Name: "Alice",
}).All(&result)
```

`result` will be empty.

---

It seems to me that avoiding BSON is more intuitive and simpler. So my questions are:

1. Should I avoid the BSON import?
2. Can I query for all matching patterns without using BSON or specifying the entire interface?
3. Should I specify BOTH JSON and BSON keys like in `json:"name"` or
   are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mgo/bson package is used to encode and decode all database commands and results, even when the application does not use the package directly.

The composite literal `Person{ Name: "Alice" }` returns a `Person` value with the `Phone` field set to `""`.  The BSON encoder encodes this value to what is logically the value `{"Name": "Alice", "Phone": ""}`.  A query with this value returns all documents with Name equal "Alice" AND Phone equal to "".  Apparently there are no documents that match this query in the collection.

The query document must have a Name field only to query all documents with Name equal "Alice" and Phone with any value or not set at all.

> Should I avoid the BSON import?

No, use the bson package directly when it's helpful.

> Can I query for all matching patterns without using BSON or specifying the entire interface?

The `bson.M` type is usually the best way to construct queries, but you can do it without it.  For example, you can query for all documents with name "Alice" like this:

```
c.Find(struct { Name string }{Name: "Alice"}).All(&result)
```

You can also use `map[string]interface{}`:

```
c.Find(map[string]interface{}{"Name": "Alice"}).All(&result)
```

Finally, you can use the BSON encoder's "omitempty" feature to omit empty fields from the encoded value.  I do not recommend this approach because it prevents you from querying for documents where the field is equal to "". Change the struct type to the following for this approach:

```
type Person struct {
    Name  string `bson:",omitempty"`
    Phone string `bson:",omitempty"`
}
```

> Should I specify BOTH JSON and BSON keys like in json:"name" or are they interchangeable?

They are not interchangeable. Specify the tags as needed for the BSON encoder and the JSON encoder.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Should I avoid the BSON import?

I see no reason to do so. MongoDB (through `mgo`) and BSON walk hand-in-hand. It doesn't matter if you import `bson` or not, `bson` will still be used under the hood (to serialize / represent the data sent back and forth).

> 2. Can I query for all matching patterns wtihout using BSON or specifying the entire interface?

Yes, you can, if you use the `omitempty` option when specifying the `"bson"` tags, like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Name  string `bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Phone string `bson:"phone,omitempty"`
}
```

Now if you do a query like this:

```
err = c.Find(Person{
    Name: "Alice",
}).All(&result)
```

Then when the filter value is marshalled into BSON, it will only contain a `"name"` field, because `Phone` is its zero value, so it will not be marshaled.

Of course using `omitempty` may not be what you want when you do insert / update, so using a single type for representing and querying persons may not be sufficient. Generally, you should "tag" `Person` how you want to represent your data, and you should use simple `bson.M` values to query, or create another struct that models how you want to query.

> 3. Should I specify BOTH JSON and BSON keys like in `json:"name"` or are they interchangeable?

They are not interchangeable, so if you only specify `json` tags, those are not used (ignored) by the `bson` package, and similarly, if you only specify `bson` tags, the `encoding/json` package of the standard library will not use those. They are 2 different tags, used for 2 different purposes, used by 2 different libraries (packages).

You may or may not specify both. If you never intend to serialize your data into JSON, you don't have to specify `json` tags.

Comment: Hey, is there any advantages to use bson type over a custom struct? or even map[string]string? I always used to think it doesn't really matter and preferred to use my domain entities' structs and maps, so I could easier make changes in the entity and not in the repo..

Comment: @oren It's handy to use structs to model your data, so you can easily work with it in Go code. It's not that handy to use structs for querying (has its pros and cons), but I usually just use `bson.M` values for querying, as queries can vary a lot, and I don't want to make compromises in the model just for the sake of simpler queries.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I usually use structs for inserts and map[string]interface{} for queries. I want to be agnostic about mgo in the application repo. It comes at handy now when I’m trying both mgo and the mongodb alpha driver. Well maybe it deserves a post of its own, to find out more about the advantages when using their package types